# Why Cost Function for Linear Regression Is Always a Convex Shaped Function?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, machine-learning, least-squares, linear-regression

This diagram is from Andrew Ng course for ML/DL:

[image]

**But isn't the cost function (least squares function) shape depends on scatter of the data ?**

For example below, the minimum will be at (0,1):

[image]

that doesn't correspond to convex shape (if you will imagine it in 3d plot), that Andrew Ng showed above.

**UPDATE**

Oh, i think I understand... my example is a convex shape too, but simply shifted by coordinates, relatively to the Andrew's example.

Am i right?

Comment: the cost function should be convex, which corresponds roughly to a "bow" shape

Comment: sorry, updating question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the cost function is given by:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \left\| X \theta - y \right\|_{2}^{2} $$

Which is a Linear Regression Problem with the Least Squares cost function which is a Convex Function of $ \theta $.

Comment: Can you please add more details to your answer? Thank you!

Comment: Could you point me what would you like to be extended?

Comment: The notation `||` is not familiar to me. Perhaps, at least provide links to supplemental resources of your choice, which will help to interpret the formula you wrote. Thank you!

Comment: The notation $ \left\| \cdot \right\| $ stands for [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)). So the $ {\left\| \cdot \right\|}_{2} $ stands for the $ {L}_{2} $ norm and $ {\left\| \cdot \right\|}_{2}^{2} $ is the $ {L}_{2} $ norm squared.